# What is the meaning of いじります in Information Technology?

Tags: japanese-to-english

Wordpress team always uses `いじります` for fixing/editing code files. I somehow can understand it is "Editing", or "Fixing", or "Modifying".

But I just want to know it clear. Google translated to "messing around", or "playing toy" :D

Below is the sample WordPress team used to modify some files, they wrote this message to inform other members do not touch those files. (They are not good at git and they don't have good environment to develop and control source code!)

```
wordpress\themes\abc\header.php
wordpress\themes\abc\css\layout.css
いじります。
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's like "touch", "play around" or "hack". 編集 "edit", 修正 "fix" and 変更 "modify" are formal kango words, but perhaps they wanted to use more loose and informal word.

Comment: naruto : "loose and slangy word", but in company, is it normal that Japanese people use slang in communication (in [Chatwork](https://www.chatwork.com/)) to inform the situation to other members?

Comment: @NgocNam It depends on the workplace. But "slangy" might have been too strong to describe いじる. I changed "slangy" to "informal".

Comment: "informal word", I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Japanese programmers routinely use it as a “いじる” or “触{さわ}る” when editing or changing code.
The code is anthropomorphic.